# Can't see why this simple if statement returns null?

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, shorthand-if

Or if the if statement doesn't return null - why this particular property can't be assigned to.

Example:

```
String stringParam = "some string";

MyClass myclass = new MyClass();

myclass.MyProperty = MyMethod(out stringParam ) ? stringParam : String.Empty;
```

Hitting a breakpoint straight after the above line - I evaluate MyProperty - and it's null!?

I have triple checked the return of MyMethod and it is true (return type is boolean). And stringParam IS being updated within MyMethod.

Supposing what I've just said above is inaccurate or wrong somehow - MyProperty should at least be equal to String.Empty. And if the MyMethod IS true but my string is being updated - MyProperty should be equal to "some string".

Why is it null?

In the MyClass declaration there are no complexities regarding access modifiers. It's a simple:

```
public class MyClass()
{
public String MyProperty;
}
```

NOTE: Although I have simplified and altered the code slightly in terms of naming etc. - this code syntactically identical to the code I have.

**What I've Tried**

I switched the syntax around for this, and surprisingly (to me) it's worked!?

```
if(MyMethod(out stringParam)) { myclass.MyProperty = stringParam; }
```

On evaluation, myclass.MyProperty is now equal to the expected, updated stringParam.

I'd love an explanation as to why. Is it the case that inline if statement's behave differently with regards to out parameters?

Comment: Please post a short but *complete* example of the problem. Something we can run. (Having a *field* called `MyProperty` isn't a great start...)

Comment: When are you checking it's value?

Comment: The only way a line of code like `myclass.MyProperty = MyMethod(out fieldValue) ? stringParam : String.Empty;` could set MyProperty to null would be if `stringParam` is null. Therefore, either `stringParam` is null, or you are checking the wrong property, or your code is not "syntactically identical" to this. Please post your *actual* code!

Comment: @Matthew - during debugging, immediately after it is assigned the value of stringParam.

Comment: Look at the getter and setter of MyProperty to see what logic is occurring there.

Comment: @GeneS - there's no get or set, as per OP. Thanks.

Comment: @DeeMac Sorry...did not catch that.

Comment: @GeneS - not a problem, thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: Here it's working: http://ideone.com/QqmQI So obviously you have omitted something important.

Comment: Can you check the value of stringParam in the debugger as well. As the others have pointed out, stringParam being inadvertenly being set to null somewhere before in the code is the most likely explanation.

Comment: I've evaluated stringParam right the way through my code - and at no point is it null. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You've changed his code. He refers to the out in the ternary operator, you don't.

Comment: @CrazyCasta - I haven't checked - but it may be the case that my edit is confusing and Tim was in fact coding in accordance to my pre-edited OP, I recently edited it.

Comment: Now you've changed the out parameter to `stringParam` instead of `fieldValue` that was there before.

Comment: fieldValue was supposed to read stringParam in the first instance.

Comment: All - we've established my OP has been edited. Please consider only the current code that you can see now.

Comment: @DeeMac: From what we see now `MyMethod` sets `stringParam` to null.

Comment: @DeeMac: I'm still not seeing a short but complete program we can use to reproduce this...

Comment: I recreated this and the value of myclass.MyProperty is in both cases the same. Can we see at least your MyMethod method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change `MyMethod`, try this:

```
public bool MyMethod(ref string parameter)
{
    // Do something with parameter here...
    return true;
}
```

And then call

```
var stringParam = "some string";
var myClass = new MyClass();

myClass.MyProperty = MyMethod(ref stringParam) ? stringParam : string.Empty;
```